# Numpy random choice with limited repeat times for each element

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random

Given `N` elements `0, ..., N-1`, and an array `repeats` of size `N` which specify the quantity of each element. I wonder what's the fastest way to randomly choose `size` elements? The output is an array of size `N` indicating the chosen quantities of each element. `sum(output) == size`.

For example,

```py
def choice(repeats, size): ...

choice([100, 200, 300, 400, 500], 5)
# a random output: array([1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

See the answer for a current solution.

I wonder if there is anyway to avoid the allocation of the `option` array of `sum(repeats)` elements?

Comparing to an incorrect implementation but without the allocation, there are around 20x speed difference when there are many elements:

```py
def choice_wrong(repeats, size):
    chosen = np.random.choice(len(repeats), size, p=repeats/np.sum(repeats))
    return np.bincount(chosen, minlength=len(repeats))

%timeit choice([10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000], 5000)
# 2.3 ms ± 7.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit choice_wrong([10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000], 5000)
# 129 µs ± 822 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current solution I have is:

```py
def choice(repeats, size):
    assert size <= np.sum(repeats)
    options = np.concatenate([np.repeat(i, r) for i, r in enumerate(repeats)])
    chosen = np.random.choice(options, size=size, replace=False)
    return np.bincount(chosen, minlength=len(repeats))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful for someone else:
random.sample chooses a number of element without repetition. so if you create a list with repeated elements according to your limit and you use random.sample() then, you get random choice with limited repetition.

example in general:

```
size = 5
RepetitionLimit = 3
>>> originalList = [1,2,3]
>>> listWithRep = [i for i in originalList for j in range(RepetitionLimit)]
>>> listWithRep
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
>>> outputList = random.sample(listWithRep , size)
>>> outputList
[1,1,1,2,3]
```

in the case of this question, it would something like this (although it is similar to your solution @Peter O.):

```
RepetitionLimit = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

def choice(repeats, size):
    chosen = random.sample([idx  for idx, elem in enumerate(repeats) for i in range(elem)], size)
    return [chosen.count(i) for i in range(len(repeats))]

choice(RepetitionLimit, 5)
# if chosen is [3, 3, 3, 4, 3] for example then result is [0, 0, 0, 4, 1]
```